# Panda dataframe column is coming as 2D array with quotation in it

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe image_train_data with column as following

```
[73 77 58 71 68 50 77 69 44 120 116 83 125 120]
[169 122 65 131 108 75 193 196 192 218 221 222]
```

I want to get the column as 2D array to be passed to KNN classifier but when I pass it

```
image_train_data['image_array'].values `

array(['[73 77 58 71 68 50 77 69 44 120 116 83 125 120 90 155 148 117 147 
152 106 133 136 92 112 101 75 100 84 68 100 78 74 69 49 51 22 16 13 35 27 
24 52 40 40 70 55 54 117 97 89 122 101 99 103 85 88 88 74 73 68 59 52 72 
65 52 82 73 60 84 72 68 84 67 73 77 56 65 93 ..] `
```

why the ' is coming ? - The csv has double quotes wrapped around that column value

I expect the column as 2 D array

```
[[ 59  43  50 ]
[154 126 105 ]
[255 253 253 ]
```

Comment: Missing commas?

Comment: Could it be that you stored your arrays as strings in the DataFrame? This would also explain the missing commas between the values as @lil_solbs mentioned.

Comment: Yes the array is stored as string - I got this dataset - how can I transformed into just array

Comment: Use .split() to convert the string to an array. I cannot extrapolate how the 2D array is created using the inputs your provided. It appears some transformation would be required to get those values (?)